# Arabic character in URLs? is it good for SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engine

I do know that including search phrases in the URL helps in increasing the rank of the website on Search Engines. But is that the case with Non-latin characters like Arabic or Chinese?
Is it better to keep the URL in Arabic for an Arabic website, knowing that it will be encoded in some browsers? or turn it to English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The content of your site will have a much bigger impact on your SEO than the URL itself. That's not to say a good, SEO-friendly URL isn't important (because it is) but site content has more impact.

In addition, your content should be geared toward your target audience, using phrases and search terms that audience is likely to use to find your website.